# indexing a text file into two arrays

Tags: c#, file-io, indexing

So I have a text file that holds 12,970 lines. I want to take  this file and make them into two arrays, list, anything that will separate the file into two groups: group one being called apollo that holds the lines 0 through 7678 and group two being called sabre that holds the remaining number of files.

The overall goal of this is to be able look through these two and to find a specific word that I am looking for, but for the time being I am just looking to figuring out how to take this text file and make two groups of lines called sabre and apollo. If I am not sounding clear for what I want then please let me know in the comments. Thank you everyone for all you do!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); why do you think “separate the file into two groups” will help you “find a specific word”?

Comment: If you don't believe that it will the tell me what I should to find how many times a specific word pops up in these groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach using Linq

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"d:\temp\test.txt");
List<string> apollo = lines.Take(6485).ToList();
List<string> sabre = lines.Skip(6485).Take(6485).ToList();
```

Of course I take for granted that your file has effectively the number of lines that you have specified.

Comment: Am I to assume that Take(6485) uses the first 6485 lines, or is that 6485 random?